# rename a file with 2 lists in bash

Tags: bash, sh, rename, mv

I have 2 text files, old.txt with the list of all files needs to be rename and new.txt with the new names.
For example, old.txt

```
23654.jpg
hello world.doc
ok, it's done.docx
```

new.txt

```
2018.jpg
old.doc
...
```

I wanted to read line by line those files and use them in arguments with the command `mv`. I can do it with one file (`while read line`) but I don't know how to manage the second file...

In conclusion, I want to use 2 files as sources of arguments for another bash command.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Another forum give me the answer:
`while read -r lineFic1 <&3; do read -r lineFic2 <&4; vm "$lineFic1" "$lineFic2"; done 3<fic1.txt 4<fic2.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another `read` with a **different** FD:

```
while IFS= read -r old_name && IFS= read -r new_name <&3; do
    mv -- "$old_name" "$new_name"
done <old.txt 3<new.txt
```

---

Or using `paste` and GNU `xargs` (for the `-d` option):

```
paste -d'\n' {old,new}.txt | xargs -d'\n' -n2 mv --
```